# Which join or query method would be possible? MYSQL Quick Question?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Very quick question!

If a table FK has a null value is there any way that I can design my query so that it does not bother joining the table the foreign key is associated to. I am currently using Left Joins.

Is there another join I could use or can I do something like this in my query using PHP?

```
if (table foreign key == NULL) 
{   
do not join table that foreign key points to 
}

else 
{   
join table using foreign key value 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post your table and key names? we can then write the query - I think it needs to be an inner join to avoid the nulls.

```
select * from table1
inner join table2
on table1.pk = table2.fk
where {your conditions}
```

For your schema

```
select * from procedure
inner join dosage on dosage.dosage_id = procedure.dosage_id
```

Why not deal with your NULL with a CASE statement and push an empty string instead?

```
SELECT *, CASE dosage_id
WHEN (dosage_id IS NULL) THEN ''
END
from procedure
inner join dosage on dosage.dosage_id = procedure.dosage_id
```

(note: I'm not the best at CASE - ;) hopefully that gets you close enough)

Comment: I can do one better here is my schema http://i.imgur.com/Dju0G.png

The table with foreign key is "procedure" and the table which I want the option to join or not is "dosage"

Comment: Okay thanks but now this query does not return a record, Im wanting it to still return a record but with or without the dosage row

Comment: I think you lost us :) - you can do a left outer but you will have a null to deal with. Why is that causing you a problem?

Comment: Basically the method I have right now contains values from my dosage table even if they are NULL, I was hoping there was a way in mySQL that It would ignore the dosage is there is no matching row in my database, so that when my data gets displayed in my webpage I do not gets null values which I dont care about :)

Answer (score 1):

You could set the clause that the foreign:key is not null i think (hope i understood correctly):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
procedure
LEFT JOIN dosage ON dosage.dosage_id= procedure.dosage_id
WHERE 
dosage.dosage_id is not null
```

but i think it's equivalent to using an inner join

```
SELECT * 
FROM
procedure
INNER JOIN dosage ON dosage.dosage_id = procedure.dosage_id
```

Comment: Thanks, "procedure" is the table the column is called "dosage_id" and the table is "dosage" that I want to join.

Comment: Thanks but now the query does not return a record if the "dosage_id" is null, so I can't get any of the other data from my table

Comment: yea I tried inner join , perhaps there is no way I can control what data I recieve I guess I can ignore it in the result and not display it on my page. Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK I think that there is no specific join to get precisely what you want, so you have to use a condition like the one in your pseudo-code to obtain this specific behaviour.

However, a LEFT JOIN would be just fine in this situation: you would not have to write two separate queries, and you'll just have to handle a bunch of NULL values if FK is null.